# Creating a clickable list from DB and returning relevant DB field data in a web page element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to get records from the database using a client side (Javascript) clickable list. The problem is that I want the clickable links to be sourced from the data in the database in the first place (MySQL).

I'm having problems passing the data to create the clickable list. I've tried various ideas and hit stumbling blocks to do with client side and server side programming (and briefly looked into JQuery but it appears difficult to do). I've been attempting this with HTML, PHP, Javascript, JQuery (briefly) and MySQL.

So I need to SELECT post_id, post_title FROM posts and make post_title clickable in the list but using the associated post_id to find the relevant data in the DB and post this via innerHTML into another element. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reload the page or do you have to load the result in an element without reloading the page ?

Comment: Don't forget to vote up on the useful answer and validate the one who worked the best for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.php** <- List

```php
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT post_id AS "id", post_title AS "title" FROM posts';
$posts = $mysqli->query($sql);
?>
<ul id="post_list">
<?php
foreach ($posts as $post) {
?>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>"><?php
        echo $post['title']
    ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<div id="post_content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js** <- Interactivity (requires jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post_list').on('click', 'li a', function() {
        $('#post_content').load('get_post.php?id=' + $(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

**get_post.php** <- Selected post

```php
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '.$_GET['id'].'';
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (($post = $res->fetch_assoc())) {
?>
<h1><?php echo $post['post_title'] ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $post['post_body'] ?></p>
<div class="pull-right"><?php echo $post['post_author'] ?></div>
<?php
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll need a bit of time to put this in but   it looks like you have provided me the way forward. Thanks again. Mark

Comment: OK I tried your method and thanks for it but I hit a stumbling block on this code line "$posts = $mysqli->query($sql);". It keeps suggesting either $mysqli is undefined or $posts is undefined later on the line "foreach ($posts as $post) {". Thanks again it has got me a lot further in any case.

Comment: I got a little further and think this may be the way I've setup the DB connection. This alternative seems to get me a little further "$posts = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);" although I only get bullet points in the web window.

Comment: I think you should use `while (($post = $res->fetch_assoc())) {` instead of `foreach ($posts as $post)`. The code is here to give the idea, I didn't check it so there may be mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've not understand correctly, but this can solve your problem :

You need at least 2 files (3 if you separate the Js Code)

Index.php :

```
$arrayItems = array()//The array containing your datas from the database
echo '<div id="listItems">';
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayItems); $i++){
    echo '<div class="item" idFromDB="'.$arrayItems[$i]['post_id'].'">'.$arrayItems[$i]['post_title'].'</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="containerDetailsItem"></div>';
```

javascript.js : (which is more Jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').live('click', function(){
        $('#containerDetailsItem').load('myAjax.php?idItem='+$(this).attr('idFromDB'));
    });
});
```

and the ajax File (myAjax.php) :

```
if(isset($_GET['idItem']) && $_GET['idItem'] != ''){
    $idItem = (int)$_GET['idItem'];
    //Get the infos from the database with the ID given
    echo 'datas from BDD';
}
```

And I think that will do what you need. This is simple PHP with Jquery and Ajax.

PS : There is just minified code. You'll need to include Jquery (from google maybe) and to make the link between index.php and Javascript.js

Comment: That's exactly what I was writing. I would only suggest using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live`

Comment: I'm used to use 'live' since I had some bugs when my links were generated dynamically, but indeed, both are working well for this example

Comment: `live()` has been removed from jquery since v1.9 (I think it was too heavy) `on()` is better for simple things like this list, it can work with DOM children dynamically.

Comment: oh ! I didn't know that ! I'll try to use on from now.
Thanks for this !

Comment: Thanks for your answer it really is appreciated I shall look over this a bit later.